# Excel VBA - write new rows to existing array

Tags: arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, vba

I have no clue how to do this so any help will be awesome. Using an array, I send row by row to an excel workbook, which does numerous calculations (too many to be programmed) and spits out 13 values which I want to store into another array. Is this possible?

```
Dim aP() as Variant
Dim wbR as Workbook
Dim wsR as Worksheet
Dim i as Long

Set wbR = Workbooks.Open([directory])
Set wsR = wbR.Sheets("Sheet1")
aP = Application.Transpose(Activesheet.Range("A1:Z100"))
For i = 1 to 100
wsR.Range("A1:A26") = Application.Index(aP, [row(1:26)], i)
'this is where I need help. Want to paste range C1:C13 into another array,
'so that I can paste it back into the activesheet. I do not wish to paste it 
'straight back to the worksheet, but accumulate all the data into array and 
'and then paste the array into the activesheet
Next i

Exit Sub
```

Comment: Yes, definitely possible.  Post your current code and I'm sure people will have suggestions.

Comment: I have edited the question to include my current code

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're are trying to make your code ultra efficient. I made a few changes that may speed it up.

```
Sub BuildArrayR100C26()
    Dim arData(99, 12)
    Dim arCalculations
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim wbR As Workbook
    Dim wsR As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Set wbR = Workbooks.Open([directory])
    Set wsR = wbR.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 0 To 99

        wsR.Range("A1:A26").Value = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z1").Offset(i))
        Application.Calculate

        arCalculations = wsR.Range("C1:C13").Cells(j + 1)

        For j = 0 To 12
            arData(i, j) = arCalculations(j + 1, 1)
        Next

    Next i
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arData, 1), UBound(arData, 2)).Value = arData
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This line paste the range into wsR one row at a time.

> wsR.Range("A1:A26").Value = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z1").Offset(i))

This loop copies your calculations into an array

```
For j = 0 To 12
    arData(i, j) = wsR.Range("C1:C13").Cells(j + 1)
Next
```

Turn off ScreenUpdating and Calculation

> Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>
> Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Recalculate after we paste the new data to be calculated

> Application.Calculate

Comment: It looks like you're just copying the input data to arData. I have already done that in my code - aP = Application.Transpose(Activesheet.Range("A1:Z100")). Then in a loop, I paste one row of aP into wsR worksheet, the worksheet calculates and then I need another  array which gets a row added in that same loop from wsR worksheet and cells (C1:C13), I'm gonna paste that array back to the active workbook but Sheet2

Comment: Thomas - Correct me if I'm wrong, but does your loop that copies the calculations into an array, is it doing it cell by cell? And if it is, is it possible to do the entire range of C1 to C13

Comment: The array is multi-dimensional.  I know of no way, in VBA, to copy data across just one dimension.    In the VBA arrays are not object there are no methods attached to it.  You cannot do an Array[0].push Array{}.  You could make an 1 dimensional array of 1 dimensional  arrays and then array(0)(0) = range("A1:Z1").value but there is no mechanism to paste this back to a range.